# How to convert an 8-byte integer to a 4-byte integer

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert an 8 byte integer to a 4 byte integer so that I can draw a cube on the screen.
The warning  it gives me is:

> Warning   C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using `operator '*'` on a 4 byte
> value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to
> the wider type before calling `operator '*'` to avoid overflow
> (io.2).   somthingC:\Users\Admin\source\repos\somthing\somthing\renderer.cpp  79

I cant change the 4 byte int to an 8 byte int because it doesn't work with other parts of my code.

here is the code I'm using the error is on line 79:

```
#include <Windows.h>
struct Render_State
{
int width;
int hight;
void* memory;
BITMAPINFO bitmap_info;

};

Render_State render_state;

void render_backround(HWND hwnd,int colour)
{
if (WM_PAINT)
{
    
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    unsigned int* pixel = (unsigned int*)render_state.memory;
    for (int y = 0; y < render_state.hight; y+=1)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < render_state.width; x+=1)
        {

            *pixel++ = colour;
            
        }
    }
    // render
    StretchDIBits(
    hdc, 0, 0, render_state.width, render_state.hight, 0, 0, render_state.width, render_state.hight,
    render_state.memory, &render_state.bitmap_info, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY); {}
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
}
void clear_screen(HWND hwnd, int colour)
{
if (WM_PAINT)
{

    PAINTSTRUCT ps;


    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    unsigned int* pixel = (unsigned int*)render_state.memory;
    for (int y = 0; y < render_state.hight; y += 1)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < render_state.width; x += 1)
        {

            *pixel++ = colour;

        }
    }
    // render
    

StretchDIBits(hdc,0,0,render_state.width,render_state.hight,
0,0,render_state.width,render_state.hight,
        render_state.memory, &render_state.bitmap_info, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY); {}
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
  }
}
void draw_rect(HWND hwnd, int X, int Y, int X2 , int Y2, int colour)
{
if (WM_PAINT)
{

    PAINTSTRUCT ps;


    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    
    for (int  y = Y; y <Y2; y += 1)
    {
       // line 79 
        unsigned int* pixel = (unsigned int*)render_state.memory + X + y * render_state.width;
            
        for (int x = X; x < X; x += 1)
        {

            *pixel++ = colour;

        }
        }
    // render
             StretchDIBits(hdc, 0, 0, render_state.width, render_state.hight, 0, 0, 
                           render_state.width, render_state.hight,
         render_state.memory, &render_state.bitmap_info, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY); {}
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
}
```

Comment: ```*pixel++ = colour;```
Here you are doing arithmetic with different signedness : `pixel` is  `unsigned int`, `color` however is `int`

Comment: There is no such thing as 4bit integer type in C++. Also line 79 in your code is empty.

Comment: 79 is the one bellow

Comment: The warning message is puzzling because I don't see any 8 byte integers in your code, let alone any casts to 8 byte integers.

Comment: @john: the pointer might well be 8 bytes. In that case, `ptrdiff_t` is also 8 bytes, and a compiler may very well wonder if pointer offsets should be 8 bytes too.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, I'm sure you're right, the phrase arithmetic overflow made me think this was an integer problem, but clearly not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your referring to by `bit` is actually a `byte`. The reason is that when programming in C++, the smallest size of memory you work with is a byte (it may vary). So its not `4 bit` or `8 bit`, its actually `4 bytes` and `8 bytes`.

`unsigned int*` can be represented as a 8 byte integer in a `x64` application. In these type of applications, `int` is usually 4 bytes in size. What the compiler is saying is that "since your later on casting it to a 8 byte value, why not cast it to a 8 byte value first, and then multiply it?". This is to make sure that there wont be any arithmetic overflow (the value is too big for the `int` type to hold).

To resolve this, all you need to do is to cast `y` to 8 bytes. And since your anyway casting it to an `unsigned` 8 byte value, you can either use `size_t` or to be more precise, use `uint64_t` (include "inttypes" or "cstdint" beforehand to use it) and I recommend using `static_cast` to do so.

**Example:** 
This code will give you the same warning:

```cpp
// x64 build.

int main()
{
    int x = 25;
    size_t y = x * x;    // <-- 
}
```

To resolve this, we just need to cast `x` to `size_t`.

```cpp
int main()
{
    int x = 25;
    size_t y = static_cast<size_t>(x) * x;    // <-- 
    // Casting one "x" will be enough as the size will automatically resolve to 8 bytes.
}
```

Comment: @ D-RAJ could you give a code example because i am too slow in the head for this.

Comment: ill try this later

Comment: it says  Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF62DFE11F0 in somthing.exe: 0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback.

Comment: @user14699592 Are you sure that your not working outside the allocated block of memory?

Comment: @user14699592 Get the size of the allocated memory and add it to `render_state.memory` (assuming that its a pointer). That will be the memory block. Then calculate the `pixel` value and check if it points to somewhere inside the memory block. If not, its an issue with the computation.

Comment: im sorry im an idiot but i dont understand

Comment: what memory block are you talking about

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227804/discussion-between-d-raj-and-user14699592).